# css Dotstyle navigation issue

Tags: css, hyperlink, navigation, hover

I'm working on this webpage, looking to implement a dotstyle navigation on the right:

http://aliantesolution.it/chi_new.php

In order to do this I've used this tool: http://tympanus.net/Development/DotNavigationStyles/

The link is the flag that appears when on rollover on a dot, but I need the link as the dot itself, because is more intuitive for the user. Some one knows how can I do it?

I just tried to change the code as

```
<a href="#link><li>caption</li></a>
```

doing this I obtain the dots working as a link, but without flag.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

done it, I've putted the LI elements in the A and used the attribute "title" for the tooltip. Code below for explanation:

```
    <div class="dotstyle">
                        <ul>
                            <a title="chi" class="tooltip" href="#chisiamo">
                            <li title="chi"></li>
                            </a>
                            <a title="organizzazione" class="tooltip" href="#organizzazione">
                            <li title="organizzazione"></li>
                            </a>
                            <a title="etica" class="tooltip" href="#etica">
                            <li title="etica"></li>
                            </a>
                            <a title="mission" class="tooltip" href="#mission_but">
                            <li title="mission"></li>
                            </a>
                        </ul>
    <div>

    .dotstyle ul {
    width: 9px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 70px;
    top:45%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    z-index:50;
}

.dotstyle li {
    border: 2px solid #FD4F00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dotstyle a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tooltip{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover li:after{
    position:absolute;
    background: #FD4F00;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    top: auto;
    bottom: -82%;
    right: 370%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    z-index: 98;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.tooltip:hover li:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: #FD4F00;
    border-width: 6px;
    bottom: -20%;
    content: "";
    left: -270%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```